# How to fix SyncContext.cs issue of TakePicture in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser to take a picture in Android Xamarin platform.
But when I cancel from picture screen instead of taking a picture, displays as shown below
[image]

And my app is crashed.
Here is my code snippet.

```
CameraViewmodel.cs
...
public System.Windows.Input.ICommand TakePictureCommand
{
 get { return (_takePictureCommand = _takePictureCommand ?? new MvxCommand(() => TakePictureAsync())); }
}
...

    private async void TakePictureAsync()
    {
      try
      {
        var stream = await _pictureChooserTask.TakePictureAsync(400, 95);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        ... 
        //Add to view model
        CameraImageViewModel imageViewModel = new CameraImageViewModel(image, this);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => HasPhotoBeenTaken);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CommentHintText);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
      }
   }
```

Is there a way can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's failing that way because your `async void` method is throwing an exception. You'll need to find out what the exception actually is and fix the underlying issue. You can find out what the exception is by putting a breakpoint at the `throw new Exception` line.

To prevent Visual Studio from bringing up this dialog box, enable "Just My Code" under the Debugger settings.

Comment: The exception thrown should be visible in Output => Debug